# Disk shows many times in Finder sidebar

Tags: macos, hard-drive, finder, sidebar

On our build server, every build there are new copies of the disk in the sidebar (see pic, there are about 100 appearances of Hsierra).

What command in the build scripts should I look for that might be causing the trouble?

[image: Disk appears multiple times in sidebar]